# Return method in Java is coming out of sequence

Tags: java

I am working on a project where I return back the values of a sequence of Java methods so that I can spew out the results.  But it is being printed out, out of sync.  It should come out as the following:

```
return
"Name:          " + getFirstName() + " " + getLastName() + "\n" + 
"Id:            " + getEmployeeId() + "\n" +   
"Hourly Rate:   $" + getHourlyRate() + "\n" +
timeCard.toString()  +
"Weekly Pay:    $" + getWeeklyPay();
```

But the calling of the timeCard.toString() keeps rising to the top when it should be number 4 in the output.  Here is the timeCard.toString() method below:
public String toString()
    {

```
System.out.println("Weekly Hours:   " + getWeeklyHours());
for(int i = 0; i < NUMDAYS; i++ )
{
System.out.println("        Day "  + (i + 1) + ": " + getHoursByDay(i));
}
return "";//I had to place this hack here so the toString() format is valid. 
}
```

Is there an adhered to order of operations as far as the output using the return keyword is concerned? Or is my code causing it to come in out of order?  Please offer your guidance on why this code is coming in out of order?  How can I fix it?

Here is the output I am getting:

Employee Id:

1001
Employee Hourly Rate:

56

Enter Hours for day 1:

8

Enter Hours for day 2:

8

Enter Hours for day 3:

8

Enter Hours for day 4:

8

Enter Hours for day 5:

8

Employee:

---

Weekly Hours:   40

```
    Day 1: 8

    Day 2: 8

    Day 3: 8

    Day 4: 8

    Day 5: 8
```

Name:          Stanford Marceles

Id:            1001

Hourly Rate:   $56.0

Weekly Pay:    $2240

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 29 seconds)

Cheers,

Comment: A `toString` method is not supposed to print -- it should return the string you want to have printed.

Comment: Your toString method should be returning a string, not outputting to System.out.

Comment: Ok, yes I tried to use the return for it.  But then it will not go into the for loop.  The infamous Java red line error in the IDE states unreachable statement?  

public String toString()
    {
       
               return("Weekly Hours:   " + getWeeklyHours());
               for(int i = 0; i < NUMDAYS; i++ )
               {
               System.out.println("        Day "  + (i + 1) + ": " + getHoursByDay(i));
               }
               return ""; 
    }

Comment: @wonu You put the return at the END of the method, not the very start. When the a method hits the return statement, the method is DONE after that line. "unreachable statement" means there's no possible way for that statement to be executed.

Comment: That's because the first line inside the function is returning out of the function.  If you have any code past that point, it can't be reached because you have already returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use StringBuilder to create a String, as in the following:

```
public String toString() {
  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
  builder.append("Weekly Hours:   " + getWeeklyHours()));
  for(int i = 0; i < NUMDAYS; i++ ) {
    builder.append("        Day "  + (i + 1) + ": " + getHoursByDay(i)));
  }
  return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: Note that you should use chained calls to "`.append(s)`" instead of concatenating the strings inside of the call to "append" since the latter will create unnecessary StringBuilder objects.  See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't double-check this, but it's approximately what you want.  (Several ways to do it.)

```
public String toString() {
    StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
    buff.append("Weekly Hours:   " + getWeeklyHours());
    for(int i = 0; i < NUMDAYS; i++ )
    {
        buff.append("        Day "  + (i + 1) + ": " + getHoursByDay(i));
    }
    return buff.toString();
}
```

Comment: Wow, you guys are good!  Thanks, both examples work for me!  I didn't think about appending the Weekly Hours portion.....that was genius.  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Your `toString()` method is calling `System.out.println()`, where is should be just returning the string representation of the time card. So while you are building the output string, your code generates console output. Then you print the string afterward. That's why.

Tony said it in his comment, by the way.

EDIT:

In response to your comment, yes, you can definitely use loops in a `toString()`. The problem is that you are returning the weekly hours string before you get to the loop, and when you return something, you exit the method. So you just need to change it along the following lines:

```
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("Weekly hours: " + getWeeklyHours()); // notice that I'm not returning anything
    for (int i < 0; i < NUMDAYS; i++) {
        builder.append(" Day " + (i + 1) + ": " + getHoursByDay(i));
    }
    return builder.toString(); // return once, at the end
}
```

If you want to be more careful about performance, you can break the string concatenations down into distinct appends to the builder. I just wanted to keep the code easy to read. :-)

Comment: Ok thanks.  But is there anyway I can still use the for loop in my toString() method?  It is now saying "unreachable statement" so its still not working for me :(  I'm sure we can use for loops in a toString() method?


 public String toString()
    {
       
               return("Weekly Hours:   " + getWeeklyHours());
               for(int i = 0; i < NUMDAYS; i++ )
               {
               System.out.println("        Day "  + (i + 1) + ": " + getHoursByDay(i));
               }
               return ""; 
    }

Answer (score 1):

`toString()` is **not** supposed to output a string to the console, but *return* a String to the calling function. This is also why you needed the `return "";` (the method has a String return type).

The method should look more like:

```
public String toString() {
    // Create string builder 'message' to hold the String generated
    // StringBuilder is used because it has much less overhead for appending
    StringBuilder message new StringBuilder();
    message.append("Weekly Hours:   ")
    message.append(getWeeklyHours());
    for(int i = 0; i < NUMDAYS; i++ )
    {
        // Append the Day and the hours for the specific day to the message
        message.append("\n        Day ");
        message.append(i + 1);
        message.append(": ");
        message.append(getHoursByDay(i));
    }
    return message.toString(); // Returns the builder as a string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `toString()` method should *return* the string you want, not print it to `System.out`.  Instead of printing it try using a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) and returning it's string representation.  Something like this:

```java
public String toString() {
  StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
  buf.append("Weekly Hours:   ").append(getWeeklyHours());
  for(int i=0; i<NUMDAYS; i++) {
    buf.append("        Day ").append(i + 1)
       .append(": ").append(getHoursByDay(i));
  }
  return buf.toString();
}
```